# Finding $\dim(U+V)$ and $\dim(U\cap V)$ of two different vector subspaces in $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

> We have two vector subspaces in $\mathbb R^4$:
>
> $U=sp\{(1,-1,1,-1),(1,3,-1,4)\}$
>
> $V=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4|x_1=x_3, \ and \ x_1+2x_2+2x_3+x_4=0\}$
>
> Find $\dim(U+V)$ and $\dim(U\cap V)$

What I did:

It's easy to see that $U$ is linearly independent, thus it's a basis. So $\dim U=2$.

For V I get:

$S=\{(s,t,s,-3s-2t)|s,t\in \mathbb R\}$ so $sp V = \{(1,0,1,-3),(0,1,0,-2)\}$ again, linearly independent so it's a basis so $\dim V = 2$.

Now if I'll find one of the two dimensions I'm being asked I'll be able to find the other with dimension theorem but I'm not sure how to find $\dim(U+V)$ and $\dim(U\cap V)$ because both subspaces are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\span}{span}$
**For $U+V$:**

By the definition of $U+V$, we know that 
$$
U+V=\span\left(\{(1,-1,1,-1),(1,3,-1,4)\} \cup \{(1,0,1,-3),(0,1,0,-2)\}\right)
$$
We do not know, however, whether $\{(1,-1,1,-1),(1,3,-1,4),(1,0,1,-3),(0,1,0,-2)\}$ forms a basis of this space, since we don't know whether these vectors are linearly independent (hint: they're not).  Given a set of vectors, how do we extract a maximal linearly-independent subset?

**Hint:** given a set of vectors $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, you can extract a maximal linearly independent subset by row reducing the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{|&|&&|\\v_1&v_2&\cdots&v_k\\|&|&&|}
$$
and selecting the vectors corresponding to the pivots of the row-reduced matrix.

**For $U \cap V$:**

Which vectors of the form $a_1\cdot (1,-1,1,-1) + a_2\cdot(1,3,-1,4)$ satisfy the equations defining $V$?  Could you solve for $a_1$ and $a_2$ using some sort of matrix equation?

That is, define $u_1 = (1,-1,1,-1)^T$ and $u_2 = (1,3,-1,4)^T$. Any $u \in U$ can be expressed in the form
$$
u = a_1u_1 + a_2u_2 = \pmatrix{u_1 & u_2}\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2} =
\pmatrix{a_1+a_2 \\ -a_1 + 3a_2 \\ a_1 - a_2 \\ -a_1 + 4a_2}
$$
We want to find the values of $u$ (and hence of $a_1$ and $a_2$) that satisfy the equalities defining $V$.

As you found, $V$ is the solution set to the matrix equality
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&-1&0\\1&2&2&1} \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4} = 0
$$
So, in order for $a_1u_1 + a_2 u_2$ to be in $V$, it has to satisfy
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&-1&0\\1&2&2&1} (a_1 u_1 + a_2 u_2) = 0
$$
That is, we need to find the solution to the matrix equation
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&-1&0\\1&2&2&1} \pmatrix{u_1 & u_2}\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2} = 0
$$

Comment: For your first question, given $\{v_1,...v_n\}$ we add $\{v_1,...v_i+\alpha v_j,...v_n  \}$ until we get vectors that are equal to zero. So it's easy to see that $(1,−1,1,−1)$ is linearly dependent but with the others it's not so obvious, if I make a matrix out of the remaining 3 I don't get a 0 row so they're independent. So $\dim(U+V)=3$ so $\dim(U\cap V)$ has to be 1.

$$ $$

For your second question, are the As scalars ? I don't think I understand what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by $(1,-1,1,-1)$ is "linearly independent"?  Also, yes, $a_1$ and $a_2$ are scalars.

Comment: I said this vector is dependent. 

$(1,0,1,−3)-(0,1,0,−2)=(1,−1,1,−1)$

Comment: Ah sorry.  That's right! You can verify that the remaining three are linearly independent by row-reducing the matrix consisting of those column-vectors.

Comment: Thanks. About $U \cap V$ I don't understand what you meant.

Comment: See my latest edit.  Hopefully that's clearer.